# XNA Vertex Buffer is drawing very wrongly

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm new to using the vertex buffer in XNA.  In my project I construct one using a very large amount of vertices.  I have been drawing the primitives heretofore with DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(), but I have grown out of that and need more efficiency, so I am trying to figure out the basics of buffers.

I think I've successfully implemented a buffer (and have been very satisfied with the performance improvements), except that all the faces look wrong.  Here's how the primitives looked without the buffer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfagK.png (the intended look), and here's how they look without: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyGeI.png

Here's my code for loading a vertex buffer and index buffer:

```
private void RefreshVertexBuffer()
    {
        List<VertexPositionNormalTexture> vertices = new List<VertexPositionNormalTexture>();
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        //rebuild the vertex list and index list
        foreach(var entry in blocks)
        {
            Block block = entry.Value;
            for (int q = 0; q < block.Quads.Count; q++)
            {
                vertices.AddRange(block.Quads[q].Corners);
                int offset = vertices.Count;
                foreach (Triangle tri in block.Quads[q].Triangles)
                {
                    indices.Add(tri.Indices[0] + offset);
                    indices.Add(tri.Indices[1] + offset);
                    indices.Add(tri.Indices[2] + offset);
                }
            }
        }

        vertexBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(graphics, typeof(VertexPositionNormalTexture), vertices.Count, BufferUsage.None);
        indexBuffer = new DynamicIndexBuffer(graphics, IndexElementSize.ThirtyTwoBits, indices.Count, BufferUsage.None);
        vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertices.ToArray(), 0, vertices.Count);
        indexBuffer.SetData<int>(indices.ToArray(), 0, indices.Count);

    }
```

and here is the draw call for plain rendering:

```
public void Render(Planet planet, Camera camera)
    {
        effect.View = camera.View;
        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;

        effect.World = planet.World;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Vector3, Block> entry in planet.Geometry.Blocks)
        {
            int blockID = planet.BlockMap.Blocks[entry.Value.U][entry.Value.V][entry.Value.W];
            if (blockID == 1)
                effect.Texture = dirt;
            else if (blockID == 2)
                effect.Texture = rock;
            effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            foreach (Quad quad in entry.Value.Quads)
            {
                foreach (Triangle tri in quad.Triangles)
                {
                    graphics.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                        quad.Corners, 0, quad.Corners.Length, tri.Indices, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

...and for the vertex buffer rendering:

```
public void RenderFromBuffer(Planet planet, Camera camera)
    {
        effect.View = camera.View;
        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
        effect.World = planet.World;

        graphics.SetVertexBuffer(planet.Geometry.VertexBuffer);
        graphics.Indices = planet.Geometry.IndexBuffer;

        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, planet.Geometry.VertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, planet.Geometry.IndexBuffer.IndexCount / 6);
    }
```

My indices may be off?  Or is this due to some quirks with how the graphics device acts with a buffer vs. user indexed?

Edit: It may also have something to do with the way I stitch triangle indices.  When I built this project with DrawUserIndexedPrimitives, I ran into some issues similar to this where triangles facing a certain direction would draw on the wrong 'side' (or, the wrong face would be culled).  So I came up with this solution:

```
Triangle[] tris;
        if (faceDirection == ADJACENT_FACE_NAMES.BOTTOM | faceDirection == ADJACENT_FACE_NAMES.OUTER | faceDirection == ADJACENT_FACE_NAMES.LEFT)
        {
            //create the triangles for the quad
            tris = new Triangle[2]{
                new Triangle( //the bottom triangle
                    new int[3] {
                        0, //the bottom left corner
                        1, //the bottom right corner
                        2 //the top left corner
                    }),
                new Triangle( //the top triangle
                    new int[3] {
                        1, //the bottom right corner
                        3, //the top right corner
                        2 //the top left corner
                    })};
        }
        else
        {
            tris = new Triangle[2]{
                            new Triangle(
                                new int[3] {
                                    2, //the top left corner
                                    1, 
                                    0
                                }),
                                new Triangle(
                                    new int[3] {
                                        2,
                                        3,
                                        1
                                    })
                        };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the triangles are being culled. So you have two options to fix this:

1. You can change the order of the triangle indices.

   ```
           foreach (Triangle tri in block.Quads[q].Triangles)
           {
               indices.Add(tri.Indices[1] + offset);
               indices.Add(tri.Indices[0] + offset);
               indices.Add(tri.Indices[2] + offset);
           }
   ```
2. You can change your RasterizerState...

   Default rasterizer state is RasterizerState.CullClockwise...

   You can change it to RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise

EDIT:

this line has a bug:

```
 graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, planet.Geometry.VertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, planet.Geometry.IndexBuffer.IndexCount / 6)
```

should be:

```
 graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, planet.Geometry.VertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, planet.Geometry.IndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3)
```

Comment: I'd already fooled around with rearranging the triangle index order.  Here's the result of switching the RasterizerState to CounterClockwise: http://i.imgur.com/MtLMz.png

Which makes me feel like it's not one blanket issue applied to all faces, but something else is afoot here...  Of course, I'm hoping I'm wrong and it's a simple tweak to how the game draws.

Edit: If I set cullmode to None the planet draws outwardly as it should, but of course without culling on the inside it's less efficient.  Not an ideal solution, but it proves to me that the geometry is at least constructed right.

Comment: Hm, but now that I think about it, I did use trial-and-error with DrawUserIndexedPrimitives to get the order those indices in the first place.  If drawing from a buffer culls differently (or smarter) than drawing manually, I may need to backpedal on some of my fudging earlier.

Comment: Just messed around tweaking the way the triangles are made.  Can't for the life of me fix it.  All the faces of blocks which point up (toward the north pole), left (west), or in (toward the core of the planet) are inverted.  I've singled them out and tried all sorts of permutations, but when I change them suddenly the others behave weird too...  This is not as easy as it was before.

Comment: No matter what I change, it either affects the culling of all the faces or none of them.

Comment: can you check this before draw? GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;

Comment: you are drawing the half of triangles, because the number of primitives to draw is IndexBufffer.IndexCount/3, not IndexBuffer.IndexCount/6

Comment: I apologize, that code was out of date.  I have had that changed to 3 since a few minutes after I posted the original question.  I know that all triangles are drawing, it's only that the graphics device is culling the wrong faces on specific triangles.  If I turn culling off, it renders correctly, but that is not efficient.  I just need to figure out why it's culling the wrong sides of those triangles...

Comment: triangles are culled by the order of its indices.

Comment: I guess I'll keep fooling with it then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3679/discussion-between-a-type-and-blau)